# How can I remove uniqueness check on email in my "user" model which extends "User" model?

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

We have a user model which extends the built in User model from loopback. We use phone number for signup hence we can have multiple users with the same email (this is actually a business requirement). We have removed user email validations but still it doesn't seem to fix the unique email issue.

We tried deleting existing user validations. We are able to create users without providing the email field. But on providing email it's expecting it to be unique.

```
module.exports = function (User) {
    User.OrderEventsProcessor = new OrderEventsProcessor();
    User.OrderEventsProcessor.start();
    // Remove existing validations for email

    delete User.validations.email;

    // more code below
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A think that this isn't possible in Loopback. Email property is commonly used in build-in User model. Maybe you should use some workaround and create new property - for example "e-mail" that wouldn't be validated and for property "email" just generate some random email.